# Let $G=(V,E)$ be the Rado Graph. Suppose $V_1 \cup V_2=V$. Show that one of the induced subgraphs of $G$ on $V_1$, $V_2$ is also Rado.

Tags: graph-theory

I started off with: one of $V_1$ or $V_2$ must be countably infinite. WLOG (without loss of generality) Let $V_1$ be countably infinite. I am not sure how to proceed after this.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem accurately? There is no assumption that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are **disjoint**?

Comment: yes, V1 and V2 are disjoint (intersection is 0). Sorry, I forgot to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to show that one of the induced subgraphs "is Rado"; that is false, because the late [Dr. Richard Rado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Rado) was a man and not a graph. The best you can hope to prove is that one of those induced subgraphs is a [*Rado graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph).

In order to answer the question in a way that will be helpful to you, I would need to know which definition or characterization of the Rado graph you are working with. Since you left that out of your question, I will assume that a Rado graph is defined as a countable graph with the property that, for any two disjoint finite sets $S,T$ of vertices, there is a vertex $v\notin S\cup T$ which is adjacent to every vertex in $S$ and to no vertex in $T.$

The problem as stated in incorrect, because the sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not assumed to be disjoint. For a counterexample, choose a vertex $v\in V,$ and let $V_1=\{v\}\cup N(v)$ and $V_2=V\setminus N(v)$; i.e., $V_1$ contains $v$ and all vertices adjacent to $v,$ while $V_2$ contains $v$ and all vertices **not** adjacent to $v;$ then $V_1\cup V_2=V,\ V_1\cap V_2=\{v\},$ and neither of the induced subgraphs $G[V_1],\ G[V_2]$ is a Rado graph.

If we assume that $\{V_1,V_2\}$ is a **partition** of $V,$ then it is true that at least one of the induced subgraphs, $G[V_1]$ or $G[V_2],$ must be a Rado graph. To see this, assume for a contradiction that neither $G[V_1]$ nor $G[V_2]$ is a Rado graph.

Since $G[V_1]$ is not a Rado graph, there are disjoint finite sets $S_1,T_1\subseteq V_1$ such that no vertex in $V_1\setminus(S_1\cup T_1)$ is adjacent to every vertex in $S_1$ and no vertex in $T_1.$

Since $G[V_2]$ is not a Rado graph, there are disjoint finite sets $S_2,T_2\subseteq V_2$ such that no vertex in $V_2\setminus(S_2\cup T_2)$ is adjacent to every vertex in $S_2$ and no vertex in $T_2.$

Now $S=S_1\cup S_2$ and $T=T_1\cup T_2$ are disjoint (since $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$) finite subsets of $V.$ Since $G=(V,E)$ is a Rado graph, there is a vertex $v\in V\setminus(S\cup T)$ which is adjacent to every vertex in $S$ and no vertex in $T.$ Since $V=V_1\cup V_2,$ either $v\in V_1$ or $v\in V_2;$ in either case we arrive at a contradiction.